# Magento - call custom class's method from script

Tags: magento2

I am trying to call a method from a class, but its not working

```
namespace Vendor\RetailOps\Service;

/**
 * Shipment class.
 *
 */
abstract class Shipment implements \Vendor\RetailOps\Api\Shipment\ShipmentInterface
{
   /**
     * @param $order
     */
    public function createShipment(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
    {
        echo'check'; exit;
    }

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap     = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state         = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $orderid = 940;
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderid);
    echo  $objectManager->create('Vendor\RetailOps\Service\Shipment')->createShipment($order);
```

Comment: is their any thing missing ?

Comment: Can you explain what you are try to do?

Comment: Yes, i have created a script, executing the script should call a method from an class (added code above).
but it seems like method from a class is not getting executed.

Comment: echo  $objectManager->create('Vendor\RetailOps\Service\Shipment')->createShipment($order); this createShipment method in class not getting executed

Comment: you class is abstrack, did you think that is working on this way?

Comment: why i am not able to call abstract class method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your class like this one.

```
namespace Vendor\RetailOps\Service;

class Shipment implements \Vendor\RetailOps\Api\Shipment\ShipmentInterface
{
    public function createShipment(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
    {
            echo'check'; exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but its not working.

Comment: is compile needed ?

Comment: Just put the log on your function and then check and yes for safer side run all the magento commands one's.

Comment: ok thanks let me check

Comment: Thankyou, could you please give some advice why it was not working before & working now ?

Comment: This is Basic concept of the OOP, you can directly call the abstract class, and that why this is not working.